# Cannot Build Rust GGEZ

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, ggez

I'm starting a new Rust project and included the ggez package in Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "Project"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
ggez = "0.8.1"
```

However, when I run cargo build, I get the following error

```
error: failed to download `raw-window-handle v0.4.3`

Caused by:
  unable to get packages from source

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `C:\Users\scout\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\raw-window-handle-0.4.3\Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  could not parse input as TOML

Caused by:
  TOML parse error at line 1, column 1
    |
  1 |
    | ^
  Unexpected ``
  Expected key or end of input
```

How can I remedy this issue?

I've tried including the raw-window-handle package manually, but I still get the same issue.

Comment: Try deleting your `target` folder to see if that helps. If not, then try deleting `C:\Users\scout\.cargo` to clear the cache.

Comment: Deleting .cargo to clear the cache worked! Thank you!